# planetary science: overlap with Astronomy SE

Tags: discussion, scope

The help pages for both [this site](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [astronomy site](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tour) say that "planetary science" is on topic.  Could we refine our help page to guide new users to one site or the other?

For instance, here we could emphasize the actual **exploration** (how we measured something) -- that's our title!  If a [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38348/should-there-not-be-a-sulfuric-acid-free-zone-in-the-atmosphere-above-the-equato) doesn't even mention exploration, then it should move over there.  That seems to be hinted at [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/is-extraterrestrial-planetary-exploration-eg-mars-europa-enceladus-titan-o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is fully on topic on both sites. Overlap doesn't matter on Stack Exchange. A question always stays where it is asked, if it is on topic there. It doesn't matter if it is on topic elsewhere.

As far as where users choose to ask a question, that just depends on what community they want to answer it. If they feel that the space exploration community will provide the answers they seek, then they should ask here. If they feel the astronomy community would provide answers they seek, then there.

Comment: Aside from the meta discussion you linked, we have decided to embrace planetary science as wholly on topic, see for example [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/583/58).

Answer (score 1):

Planetary science is on-topic here.  However, some questions might benefit with a comment like

> Welcome to *Space Exploration!*  Although your question is on-topic for this site, you may get better answers for this particular question by asking it on the [*Astronomy*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com) site.

(Besides, it seems that [Astronomy needs questions](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy) more than [we do](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration).)

Comment: These kinds of comments tend to confuse new users who often cross-post their question, which is frowned upon. Maybe something along the lines of "Also, check out the Astronomy site, our community of astronomers, who may have some unique insights on this topic" would be better.